# Using Z-tests to find $Pr(Y > X)$ with Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Quick note: this is a homework question, so don't feel the need to answer fully - prodding me towards the answer is welcome :)

I'm doing a "problem solving question" that has a bit of extra context around it, but the crux of the question is as follows.

> Given:
>
> $ X \sim Bin(10 000, 0.3)$ and $ Y \sim Bin(10 000, 0.31)$
>
> $ X $ and $ Y $ are independent of each other.
>
> What is the probability that $ Y > X $?

As part of an earlier question, I had to use the Central Limit Theorem to find the approximate the Normal distributions of $ X $ and $ Y $. I got that they were:

$ X \sim N(3000, 2100)$ and $ Y \sim N(3100, 2139)$ (I'm not sure about the notation here. Does it need to be something specific i.e. $ X_{Norm} $?)

I was sort of following the argument of letting:

$ Z = Y - X $

$ \therefore ~ Z \sim N(3100 - 3000, 1^2 \cdot 2100 + (-1)^2 \cdot 2139) = N(100, 4239)$

Then using a Z-test to find $ Pr(Z > 0) $:

$ \sqrt{10 000} \cdot \frac{0 - 100}{\sqrt{4239}} \approx -15359$

I'm almost certain that this is incorrect, because when I simulate it in MatLab I get a success rate for $ Y > X $ of around $ 93.7\% $.

Since I'm much better at programming than I am at maths, I'm inclined to believe that I've done something wrong. Have I? And is there a better way to do this, or a more succinct argument to use?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ being normally distributed are not assumed. The normal distributions are approximations of those originally binomially distributed random variables. Also, to proceed as you did, we need the independence assumptions for $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Part of the question was to "appeal to the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the Normal Distributions of X and Y", and they're independent. I'll update the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the approximating, you found the correct $Z$. This is also  a normal random variable. Then the probability $P(Z>0)$ can be found from the [standard normal table](https://www.boundless.com/statistics/textbooks/boundless-statistics-textbook/sampling-7/errors-in-sampling-31/using-the-normal-curve-161-315/).

Note that $$
\frac{-100}{\sqrt{4239}} \approx -1.53.
$$
$$
P(Z>0)\approx  P(Z_0 > -1.53) = 1-\Phi(-1.53) = \Phi(1.53) \approx 0.937.
$$

Here, $Z_0\sim N(0,1^2)$ is the standard normal random variable and $\Phi(z) = P(Z_0\leq z)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the standard normal random variable.

Thus, your simulation $93.7\%$ is a correct approximated value.

So, there is no need to multiply by $\sqrt{10000}$ in your calculation.

Comment: Awesome! Just one question... Why don't I need to multiply by $ sqrt(10000) $? Isn't it $ T = \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} $?

Comment: I am not sure what $T$ you are refering to. Probably I did not completely understood what you were doing.

Comment: I was referring to the test statistic you use with a Z-Test, but it basically get's its form from the central limit theorem: $ Pr(\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{X^\bar - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) =  \Phi(x)$

Comment: Since you already found $Z$ and it is a normal distribution, I don't see the need of multiplying $\sqrt n$.